Analytic philosophy-themed satire/comedy: any examples?
Lighthearted question, hope that's okay.
Analytic philosophy-themed satire/comedy: any examples?
There are three categories in my mind:

Poking fun at analytic philosophy itself. The analogy would be a satire of mainstream academic economists by Leijonhufvud, "Life among the Econ".

Fiction or skits where analytic philosophy features heavily. The analogy would be this cartoon dialogue between a professor of continental philosophy and a highly, highly talented student.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj2ozMbvldw

Anecdotes where analytic philosophers unwittingly show how risible something in the discipline is. Probably a few out there about Wittgenstein.



M.A. Numminen - Tractatus Suite.

You can check out existentialist comics

read wittgenstein's lectures on mathematics, he is hella funny

https://consc.net/philosophical-humor/
